# Auto Mount .vhdx on Startup

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, scheduled-tasks, storage

I have a Surface Pro 4 with a 128 GB micro SD card to expand storage space. Sadly, Windows sees the SD card as a removable device and not a permanent hard drive, I did find a guide on how to work around this(See link below), however I am having trouble automatically mounting a .vhdx on startup. I created a .vhdx on the SD card, as the guide said, and want the .vhdx to mount on startup using task scheduler.

---

I have tried to use powershell and a .ps1 file to mount the .vhdx, however, this has not worked.

```
Mount-DiskImage A:\Fix.vhdx
```

---

Screenshot: [Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvuHN.png)

I am following this guide: [Configure Surface to use MicroSD as Primary Storage](http://mattblogsit.com/microsoft/windows/configure-surface-to-use-microsd-as-primary-storage/comment-page-4#comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot, Fix.vhdx is on I:.

```
Mount-DiskImage I:\Fix.vhdx
```

Note that, depending on your OS (Windows 8), you must be an Administrator to mount the disk. If you have the Hyper-V Cmdlets available, prefer ´Mount-VHD´.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think 'Mount-VHD' would work, but I found a utility made by Medo64 that would mount the drive for me. [VHD Attach Utility](https://www.medo64.com/vhdattach/)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution better than using powershell and task scheduler. [VHD Attach](https://www.medo64.com/vhdattach/) is a utility made by Medo64 and that automatically mounts VHDs on startup.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple way to mount a .vhd or .vhdx and assign it a drive letter utilizing PowerShell:

```
$VolumesVHDX = Mount-VHD -Path C:\mynewdisk.vhdx -PassThru | Get-Disk | Get-Partition | Get-Volume | Select-Object DriveLetter

Set-Partition -DriveLetter $VolumesVHDX.DriveLetter -NewDriveLetter L -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Save it as a PowerShell script, then create a Scheduled Task to run at system startup.

Command > PowerShell.exe

Arguments > "C:\Mount_VHDX_Drives.ps1"